# #SQL UNION two WITH SELECT

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to make a UNION of two SELECT statements make it with WITH,

the selects are a recursive search of the managers and a recursive search of all the subordinates of a manager, If a EmployeeNumber has Managers like subordinates only this are mapped and not the subordinates of this managers, but if it has subordinates that are not managers, they and a recursive search of all the subordinates get mapped.

The JobCode table has the codes of the Managers

The query is for example:

```
DECLARE @EmployeeNumber VARCHAR(10) = '1035423';

 WITH EmpCTE (Id, 
              Name, 
              Email, 
              EmployeeNumber, 
              Login, 
              Status, 
              SupervisorNumber, 
              Shift, 
              CostCenter, 
              JobCode)
   AS (SELECT Id,
              Name,
              Email,
              EmployeeNumber,
              Login,
              Status,
              SupervisorNumber,
              Shift,
              CostCenter,
              JobCode
         FROM dbo.Employees
        WHERE EmployeeNumber = @EmployeeNumber
    UNION ALL
       SELECT e.Id,
              e.Name,
              e.Email,
              e.EmployeeNumber,
              e.Login,
              e.Status,
              e.SupervisorNumber,
              e.Shift,
              e.CostCenter,
              e.JobCode
         FROM dbo.Employees AS e
         JOIN EmpCTE AS m
           ON (e.SupervisorNumber = m.EmployeeNumber 
          AND e.JobCode IN  (SELECT Id FROM dbo.JobCodes)))
       SELECT *
         FROM EmpCTE
        UNION

WITH EmpCTE2 (Id, 
              Name, 
              Email, 
              EmployeeNumber, 
              Login, 
              Status, 
              SupervisorNumber, 
              Shift, 
              CostCenter, 
              JobCode)
   AS (SELECT Id,
              Name,
              Email,
              EmployeeNumber,
              Login,
              Status,
              SupervisorNumber,
              Shift,
              CostCenter,
              JobCode
         FROM dbo.Employees
        WHERE EmployeeNumber = @EmployeeNumber
    UNION ALL
       SELECT e.Id,
              e.Name,
              e.Email,
              e.EmployeeNumber,
              e.Login,
              e.Status,
              e.SupervisorNumber,
              e.Shift,
              e.CostCenter,
              e.JobCode
         FROM dbo.Employees AS e
         JOIN EmpCTE2 AS m
           ON (e.SupervisorNumber = m.EmployeeNumber 
          AND e.JobCode NOT IN (SELECT Id FROM dbo.JobCodes)))
       SELECT *
         FROM EmpCTE2;
```

Someone knows how to perform it or another way to perform this select WITHOUT the use of pointers

Comment: It's complex, but this might help: [Hierarchies on Steroids](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Hierarchy/94040/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to put ALL your CTE's at the top, and then you can use them in your full SELECT:

```
WITH cte1 AS (...)
,   cte2 AS (...)
SELECT...FROM cte1
UNION 
SELECT...FROM cte2
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can do this in one recursive cte like below

```
DECLARE @EmployeeNumber VARCHAR(10) = '1035423';

WITH EmpCTE (Id, Name, Email, EmployeeNumber, Login, Status, SupervisorNumber, Shift, CostCenter, JobCode,stop)
AS (
SELECT Id,
       Name,
       Email,
       EmployeeNumber,
       Login,
       Status,
       SupervisorNumber,
       Shift,
       CostCenter,
       JobCode,
       stop=null
    FROM dbo.Employees
    WHERE EmployeeNumber = @EmployeeNumber
    UNION ALL
    SELECT e.Id,
           e.Name,
           e.Email,
           e.EmployeeNumber,
           e.Login,
           e.Status,
           e.SupervisorNumber,
           e.Shift,
           e.CostCenter,
           e.JobCode,
           stop= case when e.JobCode IN (SELECT Id FROM dbo.JobCodes) then 1 else NULL end
    FROM dbo.Employees AS e
        JOIN EmpCTE AS m
            ON (e.SupervisorNumber = m.EmployeeNumber)
            AND (m.Stop is null )
)
SELECT Id, Name, Email, EmployeeNumber, Login, Status, SupervisorNumber, Shift, CostCenter, JobCode
FROM EmpCTE
```